# how to extract a specific text from str column and take it to another column

Tags: python-3.x, string, dataframe, extract, findstr

I have a df with str columns like: All  Unidades, Peter Lopez [QX1234]
And I need to select QX1234 and create new columns with this.

[image]

How can I create colum2?

Answer (score 1):

You can use regex and then set the new column with the result. Since you didn't provide any code, here's a sample with what you have posted.

```
>>> import re
>>> sample = 'Peter Lopez [QX1234] '
>>> sample
'Peter Lopez [QX1234] '
>>> match = re.search(r'\[(.*?)\]', sample).group(1)
>>> match
'QX1234'
>>> df['column2'] = match
```